# Php str_replace magento's categories

Tags: php

I have a dilemma about usign str_replace (or any other function )for adding tags inside a menu ( magento top navigation ),and it sounds like this: why str_replace replaces only text?I want to add some tags to that text and it just dont work. It's odd.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Well,im editing the top navigation ( categories menu ) of a magento template and i want to get categories names inside <h3> tags.

For this i have to process a variable called $_MENU that outputs the menu in this form: 
[code]
<li><a href=#>Category Name</a></li>
[/code]

but php functions work only in the case of replacing text. Dont know the reason why it doesnt let me add tags.

Comment: Thanks. Please edit your question to add those details. I don't see why string functions wouldn't work in this case. Could you also add the code you're trying that doesn't work? Maybe then someone could spot what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are working with the contents of the var $_MENU and then it's processed by another function in Magento, replacing the `<h3>` with the program's formatting.

It would be useful if you could add the piece of code you are trying to edit.

Comment: Good thought. I suspected that might be the case, but I'm not familiar with Magento.

Comment: How can i check if it's processed by other function while being echoed ? Cause im using str_replace when i echo the var. There isnt too much code to show. Just [code]if($_menu) { echo '<ul>'; foreach ($_menu as $menu) { echo $menu } } [/code]

Comment: I don't know how you are using the `str_replace()` function or how you intend to add the H3, but this
`if ($_MENU) { echo '<ul>'; foreach ($_MENU as $menu) { echo "<h3>{$menu}</h3>"; } }` should work.

Comment: If you are adding the <li> and <a> tags inside $menu, then you should add h3 in the same place you add li and a. Otherwise, you'll need either `preg_replace()` to add the h3 inside the `<li>` or `<a>` or to play with strpos and substr.